# Redirect entire directory as my home directory with mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've been looking for an answer to this for a while and I've tried many tricks myself, but to no avail, so I bring my questions to all you wise people.

I have a website all ready to go. The entire contents of this website is in the main "www" directory of the site. So now when I go to www.mywebsite.com/main, it goes to the www/main.php file. However, I want to move the entire contents of my website into a new folder inside the www directory, which I will call "ts". So now, my main.php file will be in www/ts/main.php

However, the problem I am having is I want all URIs to remain the same, so I want to tell the server that www.mywebsite.com/main is now found at www/ts/main.php instead of where it was before (www/), and that all subsequent content is also now found in www/ts instead of www/.

I imagine that I will need a .htaccess file in my www/ directory which tells the server that the absolute path of www.mywebsite.com is found at www/ts/, but I am not sure how to do that. I also have an .htaccess file inside my new www/ts/ directory already redirecting many URIs, but I imagine that I need to tell the server that all the files within the directory need to ignore the /ts/ URI, again, I am not sure how to do that.

If anyone is able to point me in the right direction, I would be much obliged. Thanks.

EDIT: I am on a shared server so I do not have access to any of the conf files, therefore I need a solution involving mod_rewrite instead. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to specify where is the DocumentRoot of your VirtualHost.
Check Apache configuration for your Virtualhost (it's maybe the default one, but you could create one for your named site). And check the `DocumentRoot` tag.

If it was something like:

```
DocumentRoot /foo/bar/www
```

Alter it to :

```
DocumentRoot /foo/bar/www/ts
```

And that's all.

**Edit:**

With the restriction of only accessing a **.htaccess** and if we assume you will limit this new folder redirection for only one DNS name (as if you make a subdir it's maybe to make some other subdirectories later) this should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
# limit this rule on the www.mywebsite.com DNS name requested
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^www\.mywebsite\.com$
# limit infinite recursion, when filename is ok...
# no, in fact not # RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# well this one is better, no loop for mod_rewrite, even on 404
# the rule is applied only once
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
# so here's the rule, map the requested file on the filesystem in ts subdir
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /var/www/ts/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Sorry, I should be more clear - I am on a shared server so I do not have access to any of the conf files, therefore I need a solution involving mod_rewrite instead. I will append my post to include this info.

Comment: My friend, thank you so much. This works great, very much appreciated and saved me another week of headaches.